# Saving Jane from a bunch of Tarzans (a matlab loop story)

Tags: matlab, variables, loops, save

I have two loops calculating something which hops out as output of some function. 
the point is to have three accessible kx before they are overwritten. how do i do that?

```
i=1
j=1

for j=1:10;
    for i=1:4;
        tarzan(i,j)=rand(1,1)
    end
end


for i=1:4;
    [kx d] = polyfit(tarzan(:,i), tarzan(:,i), 1); % until here it works just fine. 

    % and now i want to save jane from tarzan. there are many tarzans so every jane 
    % (that is, kx) must be saved in a different location. so how do i say "save 
    % kx in a double containing 4 values"?

    % i tried this but it doesnt work "out of bounds".
    kx(1,1)=kx(i,1)

end
```

Comment: Let Jane have as many sons as Tarzans to deal with them one by one? `[kx(i,:) d] = polyfit(..)`

Comment: thats 5 characters of code. i was wasting so much time on this oO. i cannot try it out right now but let me get back at you for this.